# ValidateAntiForgeryToken 400 error Using angular 13 and ASP.NET core 5

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using Angular 13 and ASP.Net Core5. I am trying to use ValidateAntiFOrgeryToken attribute and always get 400 error. Before I post this question, I tried almost all the solutions found on the internet. But, I want to clarify my case, I am creating a multi-tenant app. Every business owner will have a subdomain and separate database. I don't know if the Antiforgery token is not working due to this condition or not, but I tried many solutions for 3 days.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";
                options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            });
```

I used this configuration and ASP.NET sent antiforgery cookie with the name XSRF-TOKEN. According the Angular documentation, Angular will sent a header with name X-XSERF-TOKEN if there is a cookie with the name X-XSRF-TOKEN. Actually, Angular sent it successfully with every request, but I still getting error with code 400.

I tried to add the X-XSRF-TOKEN manually. I tried to use following a middlewhere

```
app.Use(next => context =>
            {
                if (
                    string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    // We can send the request token as a JavaScript-readable cookie, and Angular will use it by default.
                    var tokens = antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                        new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false, Secure = false });
                }

                return next(context);
            });
```

I tried to use CORS in startup.cs

services.AddCors(c =>
{
c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
});

```
app.UseCors(policy =>
           {
              policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
              policy.AllowAnyHeader();
              policy.AllowAnyMethod();
           });
```

then added `[EnableCors(PolicyName = "AllowOrigin")]` for the controller.

I tried combinations of these solutions but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the problem. My case is that I create a subdomain and different database for each business owner. The `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` works well with the following configuration:
**in ConfigureServices:**

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenKey"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

**In Configure:**

```
app.Use(next => context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.Value.IndexOf("/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
                {
                    var tokens = antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                        new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false, Secure = false });
                }

                return next(context);
            });
```

However, this works will without the Authorize attribute `[Authorize]`.
So, my solution to use [Authorize] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] is to create a custom Antiforgery token attribute.
I created the custom AntiForgeryToken using the solution in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28526906/14474303.
But be carefull, If your controller class inherits from `ControllerBase`, this means you using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`, but if it inherits from `ApiController`, then, you are using `System.Web.Http`. The solution in this link is using System.Web.Http and it will not work if you are using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.

Simply, if you will create a custom Antiforgery token, your custom class will inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute`. So, if you are using `System.Web.Http`, then `ActionFilterAttribute` will be imported from `System.Web.Http`, but, it you are using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`, then `ActionFilterAttribute` will be imported from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.

Comment: Did you tried downgrading to netcore 3.1x? I have the same problem but I'm using 3.1 with mvc but my libraries are Identity Core, EF Identity are ver5. I tried changing from JwtBearerDefaults to IdentityConstants. I get an error on the RUN, what do you suggest to solve?, can you provide all your ConfigureServices, I have been a couple days trying to solve this appending the cookies in the login, different cors, just now I get code 404.

Comment: @AbbathCL Actually, I used authentication using Cookies as suggested in the following youtube playlist
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9PEc8nf6Mw&list=PLHy1vgmVoz-IpyNKLVTxJcTKKOEbi4YMK&index=18

Comment: I found the secure has to be set to true in order to set-cookie in the browser, also in the HttpRequest needs to be added withCredentials : true.